# Tracking links when the full HTML content comes from a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, triggered-send

Content:
`%%=TreatAsContent(HTML__Content)=%%`

Data Extension:
`HTML__Content`

Send Mechanism:
`TriggeredSend API`

More context:
HTML content is unique per send

Issue:
Links within the Data Extension are not getting tracked

I've reviewed a few posts like [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114512/link-tracking-when-email-content-is-sent-in-the-soap-api-request/114520#114520).

Where the recommendation was to use `httpgetwrap` but that likely has a limitation of 100 unique links per job id (which is 1 for a triggeredSend). This doesn't work for me give that we'll send 100K+ emails that will have unique links per user. There is also [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100148/how-do-i-track-html-email-links-inside-conditional-comment-blocks-for-outlook/100210#100210) where it states that this might not be a limitation.

Are there other solutions? A client recently showed us a report for a solution that has enabled such click tracking. The content setup is the same but I am not sure how the SOAP payload was setup. Clicks are being reported in ExactTarget with total and unique clicks with a link name of `%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%`. The content in ExactTarget is exactly the same as I had configured it -> `%%=TreatAsContent(HTML__Content)=%%`

Any ideas on how this can be enabled?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found to handle this, if you cannot add the [RedirectTo()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/http_ampscript_functions/redirectto/) onto each url, is very hacky.

It involves utilizing [TreatAsContentArea()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/treatascontentarea3/), not [TreatAsContent()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/treatascontent3/). This is because TreatAsContentArea will make info coming from a Data Extension or Outside resources to appear as if coming in from a Content Area, where TreatAsContent only works on strings.

Now something to be careful of is that if you have personalization in your content (as you do) and all the content areas that you create are the same name, it will show just the initial content.  To get around this I use the below:

```
%%=TREATASCONTENTAREA(@SubscriberKey, @EmailBody)=%%
```

By setting the name of the content area to be the SubscriberKey, you make each unique and do not have to worry about duplicate content (unless you have duplicates in your sending data extension).

Comment: Thanks!

Are you aware of any limitations with this?

Assuming 'n' links per email and 'm' personalized emails, there will likely be 'm' content areas based off this approach and 'n' links per content area.

Does this solution scale? I am weary given that httpgetwrap limits itself to 100 unique links. Is there something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I am unable to comment because of my limited reputation but did want to expand on email_ninja's comment since I've been going through a ton of related threads. This is from Adam Spriggs and Eliot Harpers Ampscript guide (which I will highly recommend subscribing to), so hopefully, they can confirm. But it looks like TreatAsContentArea() is limited to 300 variations.

> This function creates a static Content Area that is stored by key for the duration of the send. It will evaluate AMPscript included in the content retrieved, with a limit of 300 unique variations. If there are more than 300 unique variations, any subsequent versions will be rendered as the first.

[Ampscript Guide TreatAsContentArea()](https://ampscript.guide/treatascontentarea/)

Hope this helps anyone like myself who is stumbling around in all of these related threads.