# Tracking links in external content (httpget) that are also inside MSO conditional comments (Outlook targeted code)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, outlook, tracking

I am finding that links in external content (httpget) that are also inside MSO conditional comments (Outlook targeted code) are not being tracked. I have httpgetwrap inserted into the href, but this looks like it is being ignored by SFMC.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Could you add some code that you are working with so we can get a better idea of how you are structuring the httpget?

Comment: This similar question might help you out: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/246593/55774